# Mac Audacity Pinned Playback

Tags: audacity, playback

I'm on Audacity 2.1.2 on the Mac - I can't seem to enable 'pinned playback' as described under 'pinned head playing' here: http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/playing_and_recording.html

I don't have the green downward-pointing triangle on my timeline, nor does the option appear in the Preferences > Tracks.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pinned playback is available on a [freshly downloaded 2.2.0 Mac Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/download/mac/).